# What's wrong with my function to update position of planet near a star?

Tags: c++, math, physics, game-physics, orbital-mechanics

Initially the code seems to work as the planet curves toward the star, but then as it should either get pulled into the star or make an orbit, it just gets pushed away in the opposite direction. What am I doing wrong? It seems like the change in behavior happens when the sign of distance changes.

```
if(!alive){
    return;
}
xPos += t * velocity/10000 * cos(direction / 180 * 3.14);
yPos += t * velocity/10000 * sin(direction / 180 * 3.14);

double gravity = 1000;
double starX = 1920/2;
double starY = 1080/2;

double deltaX = xPos - starX;
double deltaY = yPos - starY;
double distance = sqrt(pow(deltaX, 2) + pow(deltaY, 2));
int modifier = 1;
if (xPos > starX){
    modifier = -1;
}
double angle = atan(deltaY / deltaX) * 180 / 3.14;
std::cout << angle << std::endl;

xPos += t * gravity / pow(distance,2) * modifier * cos(angle / 180 * 3.14);
yPos += t * gravity / pow(distance,2) * modifier * sin(angle / 180 * 3.14);

if (xPos > starX - 100 && xPos < starX + 100 && yPos > starY - 100 && yPos < starY + 100){
    alive = false;
}
```

xPos and yPos is the current position of the planet. t is the time since the last update. velocity and direction are the initial velocity and angle that the planet begins at. This force never changes since we are in space. gravity is the gravitational constant. starX and starY is the position of the star and distance is the distance between the star and the planet. angle is the angle between the star and the planet (I have a feeling that this is what is causing the unwanted behavior.)

Comment: How can the sign of the distance change? sqrt will always return a positive number

Comment: right, thats why i have that modifier in there if the distance should be negative.

Comment: Why should it be negative? What happens if you don't use the modifier?

Comment: If a don't use the modifier, the star will push the planet in the opposite direction if the planet is to right of the star.

Comment: The force at any given time causes a change in velocity, but you are applying that change directly to the position, which is not how the equations of motion work.  The signs of the velocity increments in the x and y directions are determined by the sin/cos calls, so you shouldn't need to use any "modifier" flags.

Comment: Even if your code is "correct", it might not be numerically stable. In particular the finite timesteps cause problems if the force changes significantly over one step.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is using atan(y/x) instead of atan2(y, x) which is meant for the sort of trouble your having. Specifically when x gets small, atan2 will cope properly while atan won't be able to deal with y/x under those same conditions. I think this is the main reason for the blow-up you're having, as I take your code on its own terms.

Having said that, @Jim Lewis and @CodesInChaos are also making important observations. F=ma means you should be deriving acceleration from your forces and then integrating acceleration to get velocity (which will have to be a state variable), and integrating velocity to get position. And if you want your program to be stable when the planet spirals into the star, you're going to need a more sophisticated integration method. Your existing method is known as the "Euler method" and if you look it up in Wikipedia you'll get a sense of where you stand and where you ought to go.

An additional refinement would be to incorporate "smart trigonometry." Observe that when you have the three sides of the right triangle, it is not necessary to compute the angle in order to compute the sine and cosine. Your sides in this case are distance, deltaX and deltaY. You can thus do cosAngle = deltaX / distance and sinAngle = deltaY / distance, and use those to compute the components of the acceleration. To confirm this you can check cosAngle*cosAngle + sinAngle*sinAngle = 1. Also the sign of these is exactly right for use in the rest of the computation.

I think you'll find if you "do Euler properly", implement the equations of motion faithfully and use atan2 or smart trig, you'll find you won't need your "modifier" hack at all. It may work out that if this is for a game (your 1920/2,1080/2 leads me to believe it is), and you can control initial conditions well enough, and not step the system tooooo loooong, you might not need to upgrade from Euler.

Comment: Protip: Instead of doing any sort of atan, skip the computation of the angle and just do cosTheta = deltaX/distance and sinTheta = deltaY/distance and use those in place of your cos(angle*PI/180) and sin(angle*PI/180). cosTheta = deltaX/distance is the very definition of cosine.

Comment: Protip: You can edit your own answers whenever you'd like to improve them. Your protip is a good candidate for inclusion in the main body of your answer.

Comment: Thanks @HristoIliev I decided to follow your advice. I also learned how to have two asterisks in text without getting *italics*.